# How to share report folder to only specific users without unchecking "Manage Reports in Public Folder" in profile

Tags: custom-reports, folder, reports-folder

I have a set of users whose profile has "Manage Reports in Public Folder" checked. I created a public folder and I wanted to share a report to specific users among them using the share option, but all the users are able to see this because "Manage Reports in Public Folder" is checked on their profile.

- Is there a way that i can share the report to a set of users which
  should not be seen by other users without unchecking the "Manage Reports
  in Public Folder" permission in their profile.
- Is it possible to share Private folders?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible in `Shared` report Folder in SFDC. You can find how it's can be created and shared on by [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/create-reports-and-dashboards-for-sales-and-marketing-managers/run-and-modify-a-report#:%7E:text=Create%20Report%20and%20Dashboard%20Folders.%201%20If%20you%27re,under%20the%20Global%20Sales%20Report%20folder%3A%20More%20items) trailhead.

Thanks.

Comment: just a suggestion (and may just be my opinion) - adding "please let me know if it helps" and "thanks" to every answer clutters it and detracts from what you want it to be - just an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Users with "Manage Public Reports" are effectively Report System Administrators. As such, they will have access to all public folders and their reports. Private reports cannot be shared at all. In other words, what you're asking for is impossible.